# SELECT with array()

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm trying to filter a table to SELECT the values to certain rows based on condition. The first rather complex SELECT works fine yielding me a group of id's. But I want to use this id  group ($art_id) in an array for the 2nd  SELECT to get rows more straight forwardly. Hope someone ha suggestions. Thanks, Allen.

**the first SELECT is not included here -- I do get values with print $art_id; ...but only the last value shows up in my  image list SELECT because I need to use an array properly**

```
$QUERY1="SELECT.....etc,..."   ///this works fine

$res = mysql_query($QUERY1);
   $num = mysql_num_rows($res);
   if($num>0){
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
       $art_id = $row['art_id'];

print $art_id;
$a1 = array($art_id); ///this $a1 var didn't work in the SELECT below.
   }
}
///here is where I need to have an array var instead of just $art_id
$QUERY2="SELECT * FROM artWork WHERE art_id = '$art_id'";  

    $res = mysql_query($QUERY2);
   $num = mysql_num_rows($res);
   if($num>0){

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
       $art_title = $row['art_title'];
       $artist_name = $row['artist_name'];
       $art_id = $row['art_id'];
                 $media = $row['media'];

  echo.....etc,...../// only one image (the last, of course) shows up here
```

Comment: Sounds like a simple `IN()` clause should do the trick in 1 query?

Comment: Just a small note. `IN` is an operator. Not to be confused with a clause or a function.

Comment: As golden rule, include as much information as you can (I'm referring to the first query)

Answer (score 3):

you can resolve this problem by using just  query if you like:

let's say that you first query get the **art_id** from the table **table1** so:

```
SELECT art_id FROM table1
```

and you next query it's:

```
SELECT * FROM artWork WHERE art_id = '$art_id'
```

**The final query obtained by merging the other 2 queries:**

```
SELECT * FROM artWork WHERE art_id in ( SELECT art_id FROM table1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this to do it in one query.

```
SELECT [...] WHERE `art_id` IN (SELECT `art_id` [...])
```

Although this is redundant if you select from the same table in both queries.

If you want to test for values from a PHP array you should use `IN` like this:

```
$values = array(1,2,3);
'WHERE `art_id` IN ('.implode(',', $values).')'
```

Comment: Thanks, Alin. Worked great. With 70 vars compared in different groupings (e.g., paintings not the same media as sculpture or photos) it was complex to figure out. But you pointed me in the right direction with query within query. -much appreciated, Allen

Comment: No problem. Also note that on stackoverflow it is customary to accept the answers you consider best answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a join, it's pretty simple and much faster.

```
SELECT aw.* FROM table1 t
JOIN artWork aw ON aw.art_id=t.art_id
WHERE (CONDITIONS);
```

where CONDITIONS is the conditions from your first query.